# How would i pad a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

How would I pad a `BigInteger`? I thought using a `NumberFormat` would do the trick but it does not. I would also like any suggestions regarding my code if possible, I'm relatively new and would like to improve quickly.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public final class BigNumber implements Cloneable {

    public BigNumber(BigInteger value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    BigInteger value=BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigNumber(String g) {
        this.value = new BigInteger(g);
    }

    public String ToString(){
        String a=""+value;
        return a;
    }


    public Object CloneNumber() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        return super.clone();   
    }

    public BigNumber add(BigNumber other) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return new BigNumber(value.add(other.value)); 
    }


    public void pad() {
        NumberFormat format=NumberFormat.getInstance();  
        format.setMaximumIntegerDigits(10);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        BigNumber g=new BigNumber("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
        BigNumber j=new BigNumber("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250").add(g);
        BigNumber r=new BigNumber("7432498619952474105947423330951305812372661730962991942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250230675882075393461711719803104210475137780632466768926167069662363382013637841838368417873436172675728112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738").add(j);
        BigNumber w=new BigNumber("44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318474514457360013064390911672168568445887116031532767038648610584302543993961982891759366568675793495162176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331649063524627419049291014324458138226633479447581789257586771833721766196375159057923972824559883840758203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828801811993848262820142781941399405675871511700943903539866437282711265382998724078447305319010429358686515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829").add(r);
        BigNumber t=new BigNumber("71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938543700705768266846246214956500764717872944383776045328265410875682844319119063469403785521777929514536123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721458765761724109764473391106072182652368772236360451742370690585186066044820762120981328786073396941281142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692519343254517283886419180470492932150586425630494836246722164843507620172791803994469300473295634069115732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209550376875256787730918625407449698445083303936821261833638482533015468619612434876768129753437594651580386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954781828337579931036147403568564490955270978647975811672632010043689784255353992093183744149780686098448403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030870869875513927118545170785441618524243206931503325995940689575653678210707492696653767632623544721069793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085410526847082990852113994273657341161827603150012716537860736150108085700914993951255702819874600437535829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307949537597651053059469660676831565743771674018752758890280257173322961917666871381993181104877019027125267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526362702185404977055856299465806362379931407462559622407448690823117497779236546625724692332281091714191430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403344130655780161278159218150055618688364684200904702305308117281643048762379196984248725503663878458311487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470637832994906362596664985876182212252255124867645336772018697169854431241957240991395900895231005882295548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774760853271322857231104248034561248676970645079952363777424253541129168427686553892620502491032657296723701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522297988602722583319131263751473419948895347657455011849570145487928898485682772607771372140379887971538298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381348295438291999181802789165224310273922511228695394095795306640523263253804410005965493915987959363529746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903416981162220729771861582366784246891579935329619226246795719440126904387710727504810239089552359745723189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519861880882258753145295840992512038290094077707756721130673970830472448381653387350234084564705807730882959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581976233310448183862695154563349263665728975634005004284628018351707052783183942588214552122725125032755121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789322381957343293399464375019078369457658833523998867550616496518477518073816883786109152735792970133762177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731329241857071473495669166746876346609150359146775049951867143023521962889489010242332511691361962662273267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724768418225246744171615140364279822733480555562148189714261791034259864720451689398942217982608807685287783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090108488025216746708832151201858835432238128769527867132961247478246453863699300904931036361976387803962184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116").add(w);
        BigNumber Y=new BigNumber("66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411606618262936828367647447792391803351109890697907148578694408955299065364044742557608365997664579509666024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297649139826800329731560371200413779037855660850892521673093931987275027546890690370753941304265231501194809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791786391670211874924319957006419179697775990283006991536871371193661495281130587638027841075444973307840789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353448899115014406480203690680639606723221932041495354150312888033953605329934036800697771065056663195481234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280826165707739483275922328459417065250945123252306082291880205877731971983945018088807242966198081119777158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617721078384350691861554356628840622574736922845095162084960398013400172393067166682355524525280460972253503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690").add(t);
        Y.pad();
        String q=Y.ToString();
        System.out.print(q);
    }

}
```

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "pad"?

Comment: restrict to 10 numbers only as i currently print 60

Comment: and i want this in a method.Thanks

Comment: That's not padding...that's truncating.  You also don't mention which side you want to truncate...are you taking from the top?  The bottom?  The middle?  Are you trying to restrict input into the creation of the instance to only 10 numbers?

Comment: hi very sorry the first 10 numbers

Comment: There will always be more clarifying questions:  are you attempting to change the overall value of the internal `BigInteger` to only have 10 digits?  Are you only returning the value of the truncated `BigInteger`?  If either are true, then you should explore the API on Strings - notably `substring`.

Comment: yes to only have 10 digits?

Comment: so i should look into substrings? i was told that NumberFormat does the trick??

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this problem #13 on projectEuler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String q=Y.ToString();
String l= q.substring(0, Math.min(q.length(), 10)); 

System.out.print(l);
```